# Drop element in dynamic column inside the row by jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

At first I added `Row` (div with `rowDashboard` class) to `content` (div with `content` id).This creates three columns (div with column class) in `Row` like this:

```
<div class="ui-draggable-dragging rowDraggable" style="">
    <div class="col-xs-4 column ui-droppable"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 column ui-droppable"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 column ui-droppable"></div>
</div>
```

Then I want to add `Button` (div with `buttonDashboard` class) to `columns` with drag and drop in jQuery UI like this: ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/d6yepLxm/10/))

**html**

```
<div class="rowDashboard">Row</div>
<div class="buttonDashboard">Button</div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

**script**

```
var rowIndex = 0;
var buttonIndex = 0;

$(init);

function init() {
      var $id = 1;
    $('.rowDashboard').draggable({
        containment: '#content',
        cursor: 'move',
        helper: addNewRow,       
        revert: "invalid",
    });

    $('#content').droppable({
            accept: ".rowDashboard",
            drop: function (ev, ui) {
                ui.helper.attr('style', '');
                $(ui.helper).addClass('rowDraggable');
                $item = $(ui.helper).clone();
                $item.appendTo('#content');
            },
        });       

    //------- buttonDraggable -----------
    $('.buttonDashboard').draggable({
        containment: '#content',
        cursor: 'move',
        helper: addNewButton,
    });      
}

function addNewButton() {
    buttonIndex++;
    return '<input type=\'button\' value=\'button ' + buttonIndex + ' \'>   </input>';
}

function addNewRow() {
     var row = $(document.createElement('div'));
     generateColumns('4-4-4', row);
     return row;
}

function generateColumns(subType, row) {
    var columns = subType.split('-');
    for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
        $col = $(document.createElement('div'));
        var cssClass = getCssClassColumn(columns[i]);
        $col.addClass(cssClass);
        // Allow droppable   
        enableDroppable($col);

        row.append($col);
    }
}

function enableDroppable($item) {
    $item.droppable({
        accept: ".buttonDashboard",
        drop: function (ev, ui) {
        alert('ok');
            ui.helper.attr('style', '');
            $item = $(ui.helper).clone();
            $item.appendTo($(this));           
        },
    });
}

// Get column class
function getCssClassColumn(type) {
    var cssClasses = {
        '12': 'col-sm-12 column',
        '6': 'col-xs-6 column',
        '4': 'col-xs-4 column',
        'default': 'col-sm-12 column'
    };
    return (cssClasses[type] || cssClasses['default']);
}
```

But I don't know why `button` will not be added to `column`.

It would be very helpful if someone could explain solution for this issue.